# Display only users specific users based on relationship with other table

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to list users that are enrolled in a subject. So I have these tables:

Users:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
            $table->unsignedInteger('year');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            //$table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments');
        });
```

Subjects:

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->unsignedInteger('year');
        });
```

And this table is supposed to make a relationship between those two:

```
Schema::create('subject_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

Models:

Subject:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

User:

```
public function subjects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    }
```

Now if I click on a certain subject with some id it should redirect me to a page with the users in that subject listed. But I can;t seem to make it work. I tried something like `@foreach($subject->users()->get() as $user) {{$user->name}} @endforeach`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please write your relations in your model

Comment: As @mohammadHosseini said, have you created the relationship in your model?

Comment: Can you please show us the result of `dd($subject->users())`

Comment: `BelongsToMany {#345 ▼
  #table: "subject_user"
  #foreignPivotKey: "subject_id"
  #relatedPivotKey: "user_id"
  #parentKey: "id"
  #relatedKey: "id"
  #relationName: "users"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotValues: []
  +withTimestamps: false
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #using: null
  #accessor: "pivot"
  #query: Builder {#349 ▶}
  #parent: Subject {#342 ▶}
  #related: User {#338 ▶}
  -currentlyAttached: null
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your **Subject** Model write relation like this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

or

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'subject_user','user_id','id');
}
```

then you can get subjects like this in your controller:

```
$subjects = Subject::latest()->with('users')->get();
```

for see result use `return $subjects;`

For single subject in your view use:

```
@foreach($subject->users() as $user) 
    {{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @endyscar because you didn't pass subject to view correctly

Answer (score 0):

Subject Model:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

User Model:

```
public function subjects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    }
```

in your controller you can use has method like this:

```
$users = User::has('subjects')->get();
```

if you would like to do some custom filter pass as closure in WhereHas method for example:

```
$users = User::whereHas('subjects', function($q){
    $q->where('created_at', '>=', '2019-09-12');
})->get();
```

if you would to get users that subscribed on specific subject you should pass filter to whereHas as i describe above like this:

```
$users = User::whereHas('subjects', function($q) use ($subject_id){
    $q->where('subjects.id', $subject_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: But how can I see all the users for the subject?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I did it. I changed the model to:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

And then in the view:

```
@foreach ($subject->users()->where('subject_id', $subject->id)->get() as $user)
<h1>{{$user->name}}</h1>
@endforeach
```